# How to generate background class in faster RCNN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, conv-neural-network, faster-rcnn

I have a medical image set and I am trying to train my network using faster rCNN. The idea is to detect tumors in image. My example image containing a tumor like below..
[image]

I have extracted all the tumor location coordinates and it is ready to be trained using faster rCNN. I follow this github page.. https://github.com/you359/Keras-FasterRCNN
According to this, the input file format should be like this;

```
file_path_to_the_image, x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, class
```

When training the network, I must include background class as well. For example, `benign tumors`, `malignant tumors`, `background` as classes. How do I include background class? it is not very clear to me, how to teach the system about the background class. Much appreciate if someone could give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/you359/Keras-FasterRCNN
from this link we can see that

`/data/imgs/img_001.jpg,837,346,981,456,cow`
`/data/imgs/img_002.jpg,215,312,279,391,cat`

so you can set thing like this

`file_path_to_the_image, x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, benign`
`file_path_to_the_image, x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, malignant`
`file_path_to_the_image, x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, background`

Comment: I hope this answer your question @Mass17